# removing a column from a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a class that will remove a column from a 2d array, but I keep running into errors that I don't understand. I think I am misunderstanding something very basic here, any help would be appreciated

```
public class CollumnSwitch
{
int[][] matrix;
int temp;

public static void coldel(int[][] args,int col)
{
    for(int i =0;i<args.length;i++)
    { 
        int[][] nargs = new int[args.length][args[i].length-1];
        for(int j =0;j<args[i].length;j++)
        {
            if(j!=col)
            {
                int temp = args[i][j];
            }
            nargs[i][j]= temp;
        }
    }
}

public void printArgs()
{
    for(int i =0;i<nargs.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j =0;j<nargs[i].length;j++) 
        {
            System.out.print(nargs[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}


}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Looks like you have scoping issues; using variables that don't exist; and having a instance variable matrix which you don't seem to be using.

Comment: the main two errors says that it cannot find the symbol for my nargs array. And the non-static variable temp cannot be referenced from a static context.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a non-static variable from a static context, you need to change `int temp;` to `static int temp;` or you can remove `static` from your method declaration.

You declare your `nargs` array in the `coldel` method, so it is not accessible from other methods. Meaning this doesn't work:

```
for(int i =0;i<nargs.length;i++) //You try to access nargs which is not possible. 
{
    for(int j =0;j<nargs[i].length;j++) 
    ...
```

Maybe you want it to be the `matrix` array you have in your class? Like this:

in `coldel`:

```
matrix= new int[args.length][args[i].length-1];
```

and in `printArgs`

```
for(int i =0;i<matrix.length;i++)
{
    for(int j =0;j<matrix[i].length;j++) 
    ...
```

This require `matrix` to be static also (again, you can also remove `static` from `coldel`)

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
static int[][] nargs;

public static void deleteColumn(int[][] args,int col)
{
    if(args != null && args.length > 0 && args[0].length > col)
    {
        nargs = new int[args.length][args[0].length-1];
        for(int i =0;i<args.length;i++)
        { 
            int newColIdx = 0;
            for(int j =0;j<args[i].length;j++)
            {
                if(j!=col)
                {
                    nargs[i][newColIdx] = args[i][j];
                    newColIdx++;
                }               
            }
        }
    }       
}

public static void printArgs()
{
    if(nargs != null)
    {
        for(int i =0;i<nargs.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j =0;j<nargs[i].length;j++) 
            {
                System.out.print(nargs[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your difficulties are arising due to using variables outside of their scope. In java, variables basically only exist within the most immediate pair of braces from which they were declared. So, for example:

```
public class Foo {
    int classVar;    // classVar is visible by all code within this class

    public void bar() {
        classVar = classVar + 1;    // you can read and modify (almost) all variables within your scope
        int methodVar = 0;    // methodVar is visible to all code within this method
        if(methodVar == classVar) {
            int ifVar = methodVar * classVar;    // ifVar is visible to code within this if statement - but not inside any else or else if blocks
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            int iterationVar = 0;    // iterationVar is created and set to 0 100 times during this loop.
                                     // i is only initialized once, but is not visible outside the for loop 
        }
        // at this point, methodVar and classVar are within scope,
        // but ifVar, i, and iterationVar are not
    }

    public void shoo() {
        classVar++;    // shoo can see classVar, but no variables that were declared in foo - methodVar, ifVar, iterationVar
    }

}
```

The problem you are having is because you are declaring a new 2-d array for each iteration of the for loop and writing one column to it, before throwing that away, creating a new array, and repeating the process.